# Can i edit the default calendar list code for hiding weekend

Tags: sharepoint-addin

Can i edit the default calendar list code for hiding weekend.

I want to edit list i am having the visual studio ,designer.

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

No you can not, at least not in a supported fashion.  You can however modify it after the fact with client side code.  The other option is rolling your own calendar web part or custom view.

I have in the past used the jQuery FullCalendar plug-in with SPServices to create my own calendar.

Full Calendar: http://fullcalendar.io/

SPServices:  http://spservices.codeplex.com/

Comment: @swapnilnikam please tick-mark above as answer if it answer's your question

Answer (score 0):

Use below script it is work for me

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

    var oTable = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
    if (oTable != null) {

    for (i = 0; i < oTable.length; i++)
    {
    var table = oTable.item(i);
    if (table.className == "ms-acal-month")
    {
    for (var c = 0; c < table.rows.length; c++)
    {
    if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 8)
    {
    table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
    table.rows[c].cells[1].style.display = "none";
    table.rows[c].cells[7].style.display = "none";
    }
    else if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 7)
    {
    table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
    table.rows[c].cells[6].style.display = "none";
    }
    else if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 6)
    {
    table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
    table.rows[c].cells[5].style.display = "none";
    }
    else if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 2)
    {
    table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
    table.rows[c].cells[1].style.display = "none";
          }
         }
        }
       }
      } 
    });
    function month(){

    var oTable = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
    if (oTable != null) {

    for (i = 0; i < oTable.length; i++)
    {
    var table = oTable.item(i);
    if (table.className == "ms-acal-month")
    {
    for (var c = 0; c < table.rows.length; c++)
    {
    if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 8)
    {
    table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
    table.rows[c].cells[1].style.display = "none";
    table.rows[c].cells[7].style.display = "none";
    }
    else if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 7)
    {
    table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
    table.rows[c].cells[6].style.display = "none";
    }
    else if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 6)
    {
    table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
    table.rows[c].cells[5].style.display = "none";
    }
    else if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 2)
    {
    table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
    table.rows[c].cells[1].style.display = "none";
    }

         }
        }
       }
      }
     }
     //For week view
     function week(){

    var oTable = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
    if (oTable != null) {

    for (i = 0; i < oTable.length; i++)
    {
    var table = oTable.item(i);
    if (table.className == "ms-acal-detail")
    {
    for (var c = 0; c < table.rows.length; c++)
    {
    if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 8)
    {
    table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
    table.rows[c].cells[1].style.display = "none";
    table.rows[c].cells[7].style.display = "none";
    }
    else if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 7)
    {
    table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
    table.rows[c].cells[6].style.display = "none";
    }
    else if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 6)
    {
    table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
    table.rows[c].cells[5].style.display = "none";
    }
    else if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 2)
    {
    table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
    table.rows[c].cells[1].style.display = "none";
    }

         }
        }
       }
      }
     }



    $( "#WPQ2_nav_prev_a" ).click(function() {
     month();
    })
    $( ".ms-picker-table" ).click(function() {
    month();
    })
    $( "#WPQ2_nav_next_a" ).click(function() {
    month();
    })
    setInterval(function () { month()}, -10000);
    setInterval(function () { month()}, -10000);
    setInterval(function () { week()}, -10000);

     </script>
```